# react pagination for sections

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pagination

Im using NodeJS with React and I have a problem. I didnt find a npm module or a code that allowed me to create a pagination for a list of results.

I have a variable called "jobs", that contains a list of job ads. 
In my render function I call:

```
{this.state.jobs.map(this.renderClass)}
```

that map every job with a function.

This function is renderClass, that contains the render of:

```
 <section key={c.id} className="panel panel-featured-left panel-featured-primary">
            <Link to={'/job/'+c.id}>
                <div className="panel-body">
                    <div className="widget-summary">
                        <div className="widget-summary-col widget-summary-col-icon">
                            <div className="summary-icon">
                                <img src={image} className="img-responsive" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="widget-summary-col">
                            <div className="summary">
                                <h4 className="title">{c.company}</h4>
                                <div className="info">
                                    <strong className="amount"></strong><br/>
                                    <p><i className="fa fa-map-marker"></i>&nbsp;{c.location}</p>
                                    <p><i className="fa fa-suitcase"></i>&nbsp;{c.position}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="summary-footer">
                                <a className="text-muted text-uppercase"><i className="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;{day}/{month}/{year}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Link>
            </section>
```

In this way I have a huge list of jobs, but I would a paging.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/alexjolig/Professional-pagination-using-react-without-JSX

Answer (score 0):

I would save the page in a state,

and do something like that (say each page has 10 jobs ) -

```
{this.state.jobs.slice(this.state.page * 10, this.state.page * 10 + 10)
                .map(this.renderClass)}
```

Comment: Mmm, what is this.state.page? What value has it? In this way, will I have a pagination?

Comment: I gave you an idea of how implementing it, say you are starting from page 0 - then the initialState should be page : 0, and then either by button click or by scrolling you should increment the state.page

Comment: Wow! Nice idea! You solve my problem. I did two buttons, that now shift between different page. There is only one problem. When the results are finished, the increment button is always active. How can I block it when there are not other results?

Comment: You can unbind the eventListener when `this.state.page * 10 >= jobs.length`

Comment: Another idea is makig the button disabled when `this.state.page * 10 >= jobs.length`

Comment: maybe (this.state.page+1) * 10 >= jobs.length, otherwise I would have a blank page. In this way, I will stop before...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your need to build a component for handling pagination. Some thing like that:

```
<Pagiantion
 listLenght = {111}
 selectedPage = {1}
 itemPerPage = {10}
 ....
/>
```

I found the best component handling it, [react-pagination-custom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pagination-custom). 
It allow you custom everything (number buttons, wrap container, spread,..). Its document is well, demo is also clear.